# How to simplify this C# if/else syntax

Tags: c#

I have the following statement:

```
serverCard.Details = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(card.Details) ? card.Details : serverCard.Details;
```

I want to check and see if card.Details is null or empty... if not, write the value.  Is there any syntax that allows me to leave out the else conditional?

Comment: that wouldnt make much sense. Think about it, leaving out the else part leaves a gap in your code, namely what are you trying to assign?

Comment: The only change I would make would be to remove the `!` and swap the conditional values simply for flow of reading.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, just use a regular `if`:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(card.Details))
    serverCard.Details = card.Details
```

Comment: This is the better option IMO... The other just feels pointless in this case.

Comment: can't +1 here, advocating for {} always.

Comment: As an aside, if you are using .NET 4.0 or above, `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is probably better in this case. _Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters._ [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You can always use the old `if` statement:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(card.Details))
{
  serverCard.Details = card.Details;
}
```

I think the ternary operator is not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension method for String to check if nullOrEmpty. The regular if then would be shorter

Extension Method:

```
 public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string str)
 {
     return string.IsNullOrEmpty(str);
 }

 public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this string str)
 {
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str);
 }
```

The if:

```
if(!card.Details.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
    serverCard.Details = card.Details
```

The extension method will work for every string.